# How to use group count() in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a problem using count command in SQL Server.

my rows are

```
ItemCode    ItemName
1           A
2           B
2           B
2           B
1           A
1           A
2           B
```

I need result like this

```
Count     ItemCode    ItemName
1          1           A
3          2           B
2          1           A
1          2           B
```

how can i get this result ?

Comment: is there another column in the table that can define the sequence or ordering of the rows ?

Comment: this is a view its not table

Comment: is there another column in the `view` that can define the sequence or ordering of the rows ?

Comment: This is impossible to solve without a column to determine the sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gap and islands type problem and can be solved using row_number solution like below

see <kbd>**[working demo](http://rextester.com/KUPBIV45419)**</kbd>

```
; with indexedtable as
(
select *, r=row_number() over ( order by(select null)) from t
),
rownumbers as 
(
select *, r1= row_number() over (partition by ItemCode order by r) from indexedtable 
)

select count=count(r-r1),ItemCode,ItemName 
from  rownumbers 
group by ItemCode ,ItemName, r-r1
```

Comment: its OK but results are not in order

Comment: if you want the result in particular order, you need to use `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: `@DhruvJoshi`, your query is `non-deterministic`! It can return different result in different executions in different cases, since SQL Server will not return the rows in the same order necessarily unless you have "order by"! `S.Namdar` was right from the start. In this description we lack of information to solve it. Try to execute the same query when I insert the rows in different order (since in small tables where there are no delete yet and without index usually SQL Server return the rows in the order that they were inserted).

Comment: Here is nice post I found using google, which brings some quotes from the leading people in the community regarding the issue (this is a must to read for anyone who vote on the above solution - uing the information we have in the question at the time I write this comment): https://community.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2013/09/13/without-order-by-you-can-t-depend-on-the-order-of-results

Comment: @RonenAriely this is a pretty good answer. Yes, a column to determine the sequence is necessary. The answer has faked a sequence. Otherwise an answer would have been impossible, because the question doesn't make sense. This is a good method of handling the gaps.

Comment: I totally 100% do not agree with you @t-clausen.dk here! This might return different results in different executions. It is true that there is no solution without getting more information, but it is up to us to explain the OP what is the issue and what/how to fix it. The best solution at this time is that we need more information. This solution is worse then no solution! The user will get the same result most of the times probably and he will think that this is the right solution. Therefore he might count on this solution in his critical business app, which can lead to huge serious issues!

Comment: I noticed that the response marked as answer. I hope the sake of the user future that he read my comment and that he understood what he is doing before he will use this solution. Even the number of rows which returns in this query can be different according to the order SQL Server will returned the rows from the table. If this fit to the OP, so be it. I think that the OP does not have the knowledge to understand yet, and you mislead him to do something that might be huge mistake in the future. In this case, I hope and I will be happy if I am mistaken and all will be fine :-)

Comment: @RonenAriely you have to imagine that the sequence is based on a column in the table. `order by(select null)` replace´the null with the actual sequence column. This should have been included in the answer. It should be obvious that this column is needed from the comments below the question.

Comment: The question is '*will the OP imagine this?!?*' will future people that will see this solution marked as answer will understand this?!? this is a mistake in my opinion!. By the way, if this was in the MSDN forums, where I have the power as moderator, then I would un-mark the answer as answer even if the OP marked it, unless he explicitly say that he is OK with getting different results in different executions (or he understand the issue and how to fix it without imagine). I will make him understand the mistake instead of explain what we can imagine :-)

Comment: if the whole "order by" issue was presented in the response well (explained well) as part of the answer, together with the explanation you gave regarding what need to be change once we do have the missing information, then the users will not need to imagine, and in that case I could conciser the response as a good answer...

Comment: @ronen-ariely feel free to update answer. I'm shifting home so will not be able to do so till about another few hours.

Comment: Is it possible with Group rollup or group cube ?